# IONIC- removing previous page from view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently working with two pages which all uses one tab view. When a user first launches the page, the login page show first, when the user logs in, he/she is been directed to a different page which also uses that same tab view. I want to remove the home page from history after a user login. With my current script when the user logs in the back is been disabled from the header but when the user taps on the tab, it brings him to the login page again.

```
.controller('login_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$timeout','$ionicModal','$ionicLoading','$ionicPopup','$location','$cordovaToast','$location','$ionicHistory',function($scope,$http,$timeout,$ionicModal,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$location,$cordovaToast,$location,$ionicHistory){

            ///alert if connection fails
                $scope.connect = function() {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error',
                template: '<p align="center">Internet Connectivity Problem</p>',
                });
                };

    ///alert if username or password is wrong
    $scope.mainloginAlert = function() {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error',
                template: '<p align="center">Incorrect Username or Password</p>',
                });
                };


    $scope.mainlogin= function(){
    $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Please Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post("http://sample.com/login.php",
        {'user':$scope.login_username,'pass':$scope.password})
        .success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.data_msg=(data.message)



            if($scope.data_msg==="Incorrect Username or Password"){
            $scope.mainloginAlert()
            {$ionicLoading.hide();}
        }
                else{
                if(data != "Incorrect Username or Password"){
                localStorage.setItem("account_number",(data[0].Account_Number));
                $scope.account_number= localStorage.getItem("account_number");

                $http.post("http://gwclebilling.com/blay/server_scripts/customer.php",{'id':$scope.account_number}).success(function(data){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                $location.path ('tab/account');
                {$ionicLoading.hide();}
                    })
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: true
                })
                    }
                }

                }).error(function(error){
                console.error(error);
                {$ionicLoading.hide();}
                $scope.connect()
                    });

  }


}])
```

Comment: check if this helps https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/clear-navigation-history-prevent-back-button-use-android/1458

Answer (score 0):

Store your $scope.account_number into localstorage first once login.like

```
localStorage.accNum = $scope.account_number;
```

when you open next time, check this is undefined or not.like

```
if(localStorage.accNum == undefined){
   //write code to open login page
}else{
   //write code to open other than login page
}
```

you can clear localStorage.accNum once user logged out. like

localStorage.accNum = "";